# How to send bearer authorization in the url of my webview ,

Tags: flutter, webview, header, authorization, bearer-token

I'm trying to send bearer authorization to my web view URL , I'm using flutter_webview_pro 1.0.3 package .
I think that it's impossible to send headers with this library.
So I need to know if it's possible to send bearer authorization in the url manually and how.

here is my code :

```
WebView(
        initialUrl:
           baseUrl+"/paypal/login?${widget.montant}",
          
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController ) {
          
          Map<String, String> headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + widget.token};
          headers: headers;
          
          _controller.complete(webViewController );
        },
        onProgress: (int progress) {
          if(progress>100){
            
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                              SnackBar(content: Text("WebView is loading (progress : $progress%)")));
          }
          
          print("WebView is loading (progress : $progress%)");
        },
       
        navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
          
          return NavigationDecision.navigate;
        },
        onPageStarted: (String url) {
          print('Page started loading: $url');
        },
        onPageFinished: (String url) {
          if(url.contains("dashboard")){
            Navigator.pop(context);
          }
          print('Page finished loading: $url');
          
        },
        gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
        geolocationEnabled: true,
      );
```

Comment: why do you want to use webview for that? use http client for communicating with an API and webview for displaying websites (unless it's a website even though the URL contains `api`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.
I just changed **initialUrl** with **webViewController.loadUrl**

```
onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController ) {
webViewController.loadUrl("url?${widget.montant}", headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer ${widget.token}"});
          _controller.complete(webViewController );
        },
```